# form data passed timestamp convert to byte[] in webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

i have passed a timestamp through formData in jquery to a webservice. below is my js file code

```
function SaveNotification() {
var data = getData();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Webservice/General.asmx/SaveNotification",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,        
    data: data,
    success: imgSuccess,
    error: handleResponse
});
}

function getData() {
var data = new FormData();
data.append("Image", $("#fileBox")[0].files[0]);
data.append("id", Number(notificationId));
data.append("description",$("#txtDesc").val());
data.append("timestamp", getTimeStamp());

return data;
}

function getTimeStamp() {
var timeStamp = [];
if (Number(notificationId) != -1) {
    $(notifications).each(function(index, item) {
        if (item.ID == Number(notificationId)) {
            timeStamp = JSON.stringify(item.TimeStamp);
        }
    });
}
return timeStamp;
}
```

now what i want is convert this timestamp to byte[]. i have used some codes but it will convert only to different byte[]. not the exact timpstamp which is created by sql server. below code is what i used to convert it to byte[] in my webservice

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["timestamp"] != "")
                    timeStamp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["timestamp"]);
```

in immediate window HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["timestamp"] gives "[0,0,0,0,0,0,24,174]" result which is correct but a string array. after i convert using above code it will give

> {byte[20]}
>       [0]: 91
>       [1]: 48
>       [2]: 44
>       [3]: 48
>       [4]: 44
>       [5]: 48
>       [6]: 44
>       [7]: 48
>       [8]: 44
>       [9]: 48
>       [10]: 44
>       [11]: 48
>       [12]: 44
>       [13]: 50
>       [14]: 52
>       [15]: 44
>       [16]: 49
>       [17]: 55
>       [18]: 52
>       [19]: 93

so how can i convert timestamp to byte[] what i want to... ([0,0,0,0,0,0,24,174])

Comment: Everything about this is confusing. Firstly, why not just return a regular timestamp from SQL and multiply with thousand to get a javascript timestamp? Secondly, what is `notificationId`, where is it coming from, and why do you have a loop that just overwrites the same value on every iteration ?

Comment: @adeneo sorry i did not post all my code here. i'm trying to update my record. i used jquery array to store all my records and when updating i'm getting the record from this array using its id, that's the notificationId. as you know it should match the timestamp we sending and the timestamp in the table. i just want to pass timestamp to the webservice and send it with stored procedure